# Negative decimals in (parentheses) not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, forms, decimal

I'm using `String.Format("{0:####.00;(####.00);0.00}", Model)` to display a negative currency of -1600.00 as `(1600.00)`. However, decimal inputs in this format cannot be parsed by the model binder.

I suspect I need to change a culture setting, but I don't know where.

How do I tell my ASP.NET MVC 3 application that a decimal form input value of (1600.00) means -1600.00?

---

**Solved. See answer below.**

Answer (score 1):

Solved by keeping my display templates' formatting and changing my editor templates to use a standard minus without parentheses.

Comment: You should post the edit code you did to make this work.